# Regex to replace exact matching string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex expression to replace the string which exactly matches it.

For e.g : - `var a = '@test @te @world @dimension`'

I need to replace '`@te`' .

Since '`@te`' exists in `@test` as well so Replace statement is replacing the `@test` in my case.

So could anyone please let me know how can this be done.

Just the exact matching string needs to be replaced.

Comment: `@te\b` ? ............

Comment: check out, http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more info on regex patterns and their uses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
/\@te\b/
```

Comment: Great. If you could mark this as the correct answer, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var a = '@test @te @world @dimension';
var b = a.replace(/@te /, '');
```

Comment: Exactly **what** isn't a regular expression?

Comment: I think this is what OP wants. OP has tagged javascript and asked help to replace desired string with his choice so I gave this example.