# Replace whole word with jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

I have the following code that replaces the word "egg" in jquery. The problem is it also replaces the word "eggplant". Is there a way to make sure it only replaces the word egg when it's the whole word?

```
$(".ingredient").text(function () {
return $(this).text().replace("egg", "Henergy Cage Free egg"); 
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080037/match-and-replace-whole-words-in-javascript

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210616/regex-to-replace-exact-matching-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".ingredient").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\begg\b/, "Henergy Cage Free egg"); 
});
```

Would replace the word egg, as a word boundary. So should replace `egg` but not `eggplant`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".ingredient").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace(/\begg\b/, "Henergy Cage Free egg");
    });
```

egg

```
<div class="ingredient">eggplant</div>
```